# How to use if statements to correctly format the date of the array list from File .txt

Tags: java, arrays, file, if-statement, simpledateformat

This is Data.txt:

Station ID: This is the unique ID for the weather station that recorded the data.

YearMonthDay: 8 digit number that uses 4 digits each for year (first two), month (middle two) and day (last 2).

Tmax: Maximum temperature for the date

Tmin: Minimum temperature for the date

Snow: Amount of snowfall for the date

Precip: Total precipitation for the day

```
14939   20150801    89  63  0   0
14939   20150802    96  71  0   0
14939   20150803    86  67  0   0
14939   20150804    89  67  0   0.17
14939   20150805    83  70  0   0
14939   20150806    82  63  0   0.03
14939   20150807    93  67  0   0
14939   20150808    88  69  0   0.36
14939   20150809    89  74  0   0
14939   20150810    85  63  0   0
14939   20150811    87  58  0   0
14939   20150812    88  59  0   0
14939   20150813    90  62  0   0
14939   20150814    92  68  0   0
14939   20150815    92  64  0   0
14939   20150816    94  69  0   0
14939   20150817    78  68  0   1.72
14939   20150818    75  56  0   0.36
14939   20150819    77  53  0   0.08
14939   20150820    85  52  0   0
14939   20150821    86  64  0   0
14939   20150822    91  65  0   0.01    
14939   20150823    76  50  0   0
14939   20150824    82  46  0   0
14939   20150825    82  51  0   0
14939   20150826    85  55  0   0
14939   20150827    87  66  0   0.31
14939   20150828    80  64  0   0.74
14939   20150829    74  61  0   0
14939   20150830    78  62  0   0
14939   20150831    88  62  0   0
14939   20140801    86  63  0   0
14939   20140802    90  59  0   0.06
14939   20140803    93  66  0   0
14939   20140804    87  64  0   0
14939   20140805    93  67  0   0
14939   20140806    83  71  0   0.21
14939   20140807    81  68  0   0
14939   20140808    83  70  0   0
14939   20140809    85  68  0   0.55
14939   20140810    85  68  0   0.08
14939   20140811    80  57  0   0
14939   20140812    81  51  0   0
14939   20140813    87  53  0   0
14939   20140814    89  57  0   0
14939   20140815    76  69  0   0.23
14939   20140816    87  69  0   0
14939   20140817    92  67  0   0.31
14939   20140818    91  62  0   0.01
14939   20140819    93  66  0   0
14939   20140820    96  74  0   0
14939   20140821    90  71  0   0.23
14939   20140822    93  73  0   0.18
14939   20140823    95  69  0   0.21
14939   20140824    91  70  0   0
14939   20140825    83  64  0   0
14939   20140826    81  63  0   1.45
14939   20140827    77  67  0   0.65
14939   20140828    82  69  0   2.66
14939   20140829    75  67  0   0
14939   20140830    87  64  0   0
14939   20140831    92  66  0   0.71
14939   20130801    89  62  0   0.69
14939   20130802    84  65  0   0.06
14939   20130803    80  62  0   0
14939   20130804    79  61  0   0
14939   20130805    86  70  0   0
14939   20130806    88  67  0   0
14939   20130807    85  66  0   0
14939   20130808    79  65  0   0
14939   20130809    83  60  0   0
14939   20130810    84  54  0   0
14939   20130811    87  61  0   0.01
14939   20130812    85  65  0   0.09
14939   20130813    80  60  0   0
14939   20130814    78  56  0   0
14939   20130815    70  63  0   0.25
14939   20130816    75  62  0   0
14939   20130817    80  60  0   0
14939   20130818    81  52  0   0
14939   20130819    87  63  0   0
14939   20130820    91  70  0   0
14939   20130821    92  69  0   0
14939   20130822    86  68  0   0.01
14939   20130823    92  71  0   0
14939   20130824    94  75  0   0
14939   20130825    96  73  0   0
14939   20130826    97  75  0   0
14939   20130827    98  72  0   0
14939   20130828    95  67  0   0
14939   20130829    98  68  0   0
14939   20130830    100 70  0   0
14939   20130831    96  72  0   0
14939   20120801    100 72  0   0
14939   20120802    96  70  0   0.11
14939   20120803    99  69  0   0
14939   20120804    84  59  0   0
14939   20120805    89  55  0   0
14939   20120806    97  60  0   0
14939   20120807    102 69  0   0
14939   20120808    103 67  0   0
14939   20120809    87  65  0   0
14939   20120810    82  55  0   0
14939   20120811    83  51  0   0.01
14939   20120812    84  63  0   0
14939   20120813    80  57  0   0
14939   20120814    87  57  0   0
14939   20120815    94  58  0   0
14939   20120816    77  49  0   0
14939   20120817    82  44  0   0
14939   20120818    78  45  0   0
14939   20120819    83  46  0   0
14939   20120820    89  48  0   0
14939   20120821    94  53  0   0
14939   20120822    93  58  0   0
14939   20120823    93  66  0   0
14939   20120824    77  68  0   0.13
14939   20120825    76  65  0   0.05
14939   20120826    85  62  0   0
14939   20120827    93  57  0   0
14939   20120828    97  60  0   0
14939   20120829    98  63  0   0
14939   20120830    100 66  0   0
14939   20120831    99  58  0   0
14939   20110801    104 75  0   0
14939   20110802    95  76  0   0
14939   20110803    89  69  0   0
14939   20110804    86  71  0   0.13
14939   20110805    85  71  0   0.45
14939   20110806    92  67  0   0.57
14939   20110807    88  68  0   0.02
14939   20110808    87  66  0   0.13
14939   20110809    84  63  0   0
14939   20110810    80  62  0   0
14939   20110811    85  56  0   1.06
14939   20110812    84  62  0   0.56
14939   20110813    83  62  0   0
14939   20110814    83  57  0   0
14939   20110815    79  65  0   0.64
14939   20110816    77  67  0   0
14939   20110817    85  65  0   0
14939   20110818    90  65  0   0.66
14939   20110819    84  63  0   0.05
14939   20110820    80  66  0   0
14939   20110821    85  61  0   0
14939   20110822    88  71  0   0
14939   20110823    95  76  0   0
14939   20110824    87  59  0   0
14939   20110825    84  55  0   0
14939   20110826    87  62  0   0
14939   20110827    86  61  0   0
14939   20110828    81  64  0   0
14939   20110829    82  57  0   0
14939   20110830    84  65  0   2.62
14939   20110831    92  66  0   0
14939   20100801    90  64  0   0
14939   20100802    94  74  0   0
14939   20100803    91  73  0   0
14939   20100804    88  70  0   0.44
14939   20100805    87  66  0   0
14939   20100806    87  66  0   0
14939   20100807    92  68  0   0
14939   20100808    98  75  0   0
14939   20100809    95  72  0   0
14939   20100810    96  74  0   0
14939   20100811    99  69  0   0
14939   20100812    100 67  0   0
14939   20100813    95  70  0   0.02
14939   20100814    92  63  0   0
14939   20100815    86  57  0   0
14939   20100816    90  59  0   0.27
14939   20100817    69  64  0   0.18
14939   20100818    84  65  0   0
14939   20100819    95  65  0   0
14939   20100820    89  72  0   0.09
14939   20100821    95  67  0   0
14939   20100822    94  64  0   0
14939   20100823    94  66  0   0.27
14939   20100824    81  56  0   0.7
14939   20100825    85  52  0   0
14939   20100826    87  57  0   0
14939   20100827    87  54  0   0
14939   20100828    91  58  0   0
14939   20100829    93  63  0   0
14939   20100830    94  73  0   0
14939   20100831    94  68  0   0.84
14939   20090801    78  58  0   0
14939   20090802    94  54  0   0
14939   20090803    94  65  0   0
14939   20090804    88  66  0   0.07
14939   20090805    85  63  0   0.04
14939   20090806    84  59  0   0
14939   20090807    97  73  0   0.04
14939   20090808    102 76  0   0
14939   20090809    83  66  0   0.11
14939   20090810    88  59  0   0
14939   20090811    89  57  0   0
14939   20090812    96  66  0   0
14939   20090813    93  65  0   0
14939   20090814    93  62  0   0
14939   20090815    84  67  0   0.95
14939   20090816    81  63  0   0.6
14939   20090817    83  57  0   0
14939   20090818    84  58  0   0
14939   20090819    83  66  0   0.33
14939   20090820    77  59  0   0
14939   20090821    74  53  0   0
14939   20090822    79  48  0   0
14939   20090823    83  55  0   0
14939   20090824    91  63  0   0
14939   20090825    86  70  0   0
14939   20090826    77  66  0   1.06
14939   20090827    78  58  0   0
14939   20090828    78  52  0   0
14939   20090829    72  51  0   0
14939   20090830    71  48  0   0
14939   20090831    73  42  0   0
14939   20080801    93  71  0   0
14939   20080802    99  73  0   0
14939   20080803    102 70  0   0
14939   20080804    93  75  0   0
14939   20080805    85  65  0   0
14939   20080806    86  63  0   0
14939   20080807    90  60  0   0
14939   20080808    90  61  0   0
14939   20080809    81  66  0   0.24
14939   20080810    88  59  0   0.26
14939   20080811    84  65  0   0.4
14939   20080812    87  63  0   0.02
14939   20080813    91  65  0   0
14939   20080814    86  66  0   0
14939   20080815    84  62  0   0
14939   20080816    84  58  0   0
14939   20080817    86  55  0   0
14939   20080818    89  60  0   0
14939   20080819    88  60  0   0
14939   20080820    87  57  0   0
14939   20080821    84  66  0   0
14939   20080822    95  70  0   0
14939   20080823    83  63  0   0
14939   20080824    83  61  0   0.46
14939   20080825    83  56  0   0
14939   20080826    82  59  0   0
14939   20080827    87  64  0   0.4
14939   20080828    90  57  0   0
14939   20080829    89  50  0   0
14939   20080830    91  54  0   0
14939   20080831    93  69  0   0
14939   20070801    89  68  0   0.28
14939   20070802    90  66  0   0
14939   20070803    90  67  0   0.16
14939   20070804    96  76  0   0
14939   20070805    92  74  0   0
14939   20070806    93  73  0   0.21
14939   20070807    85  72  0   0.44
14939   20070808    90  72  0   1.34
14939   20070809    96  74  0   0
14939   20070810    96  67  0   0.46
14939   20070811    97  72  0   0
14939   20070812    95  72  0   0.12
14939   20070813    100 70  0   0
14939   20070814    98  75  0   0
14939   20070815    92  71  0   0
14939   20070816    83  72  0   0.11
14939   20070817    85  71  0   0.1
14939   20070818    93  73  0   0
14939   20070819    91  73  0   0
14939   20070820    96  70  0   0.39
14939   20070821    95  70  0   0
14939   20070822    88  67  0   0.96
14939   20070823    86  67  0   0.55
14939   20070824    75  63  0   0.01
14939   20070825    81  58  0   0
14939   20070826    89  68  0   0
14939   20070827    95  75  0   0
14939   20070828    94  67  0   0.65
14939   20070829    76  62  0   0.02
14939   20070830    80  57  0   0
14939   20070831    83  56  0   0
14939   20060801    105 79  0   0
14939   20060802    85  65  0   0
14939   20060803    90  58  0   0
14939   20060804    91  54  0   0
14939   20060805    102 70  0   0.1
14939   20060806    91  72  0   0.4
14939   20060807    82  67  0   0.09
14939   20060808    86  66  0   1.71
14939   20060809    100 74  0   0
14939   20060810    90  74  0   0.04
14939   20060811    91  69  0   0
14939   20060812    90  70  0   0
14939   20060813    82  71  0   0.11
14939   20060814    83  58  0   0
14939   20060815    85  53  0   0
14939   20060816    87  64  0   0.49
14939   20060817    90  70  0   0.14
14939   20060818    88  69  0   0.6
14939   20060819    78  61  0   0.09
14939   20060820    81  57  0   0
14939   20060821    89  60  0   0
14939   20060822    87  63  0   0
14939   20060823    91  63  0   0
14939   20060824    95  68  0   0
14939   20060825    83  68  0   0.02
14939   20060826    80  63  0   0
14939   20060827    76  62  0   0.26
14939   20060828    67  63  0   0
14939   20060829    80  59  0   0
14939   20060830    82  52  0   0
14939   20060831    83  60  0   0
```

How I correct all of the YearMonthDay (20150801) to August 2015

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` depending on which Java version you are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20150829");
String ds = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println(ds);
```

This will show: August 2015